# How to get the time information of a record in a Dynamodb Stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to use Dynamodb streams log the changes in a table for analytics purposes. I am using the Java SDK and everything is working, I can see all the changes made to the table and get old and new images, however I could not find any timestamp for the change that happened. Since I want to keep a log of these changes, I need the exact time that it happened but I could not find any time information in the record.

Where can I see the datetime information about when the change was made?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Streams doesn't provide a timestamp in the records ( see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dynamodbstreams/latest/APIReference/API_GetRecords.html for data available )

Perhaps you could set a "lastModified" attribute when you update an item in the table. This would then be available in the "NewImage" data.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that is the conclusion I have reached.

Comment: Streams now provide "ApproximateCreationDateTime" which is unix timestamp. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_StreamRecord.html

Answer (score 2):

This already has an accepted answer (that the info is not present), but perhaps something has changed because I'm seeing a timestamp in the stream.

For example, when I change a DynamoDB item, my Lambda (which uses nodejs 4.3 platform, but I don't think that is relevant) receives the usual array of records, where record.dynamodb for the 'modify' has

```
{
    "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1468175100,
    "Keys": { "id": { "S": "stringid" } },
    "NewImage": {
    ...
```

The 'ApproximateCreationDateTime' is not in my Dynamo item - it appears to be a unix timestamp (s, not ms) inserted into the stream by AWS.  I haven't really investigated it further by perhaps this would satisfy the original request.

Comment: In my experience, this value isn't accurate (30-60 seconds) off making it pretty useless for things that can change more frequently than that.